# Can't move mouse cursor while typing on Acer laptop

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse

I've been having issues with not being able to move my mouse while typing, and I've been everywhere I can think of to fix it, but nothing works. I went through my mouse settings and changed some things, but I'm still having the same issues. I like to game on this computer, so this is kind of a big setback while gaming. I have an ELAN pointing device.

Answer (score 1):

I think your touchpad software is blocking cursor.

Some laptops are very bad designed, have touchpad too big or in wrong place, so you can touch it accidently while typing. Manufacturers add some software that "help" with that.

So... I guess this is touchpad driver/software fault.